# Advice on the use of own packages

Tags: packages

I'm making my own packages and I have one which is a "minimal set of required packages"

Is it better to include it in my `.tex` files (with other packages) or in my `.sty` files ?

Or with example:

in `poster.sty`

```
\RequirePackage{minimalSet}
```

and in `myCurrentPoster.tex`

```
\usepackage{poster}
```

OR

in `myCurrentPoser.tex`

```
\usepackage{minimalSet}
\usepackage{poster}
```

Comment: If any code in `poster` depends on code in `minimalSet` to operate, then clearly you need the first option. If the code are independent, it is largely a question of aesthetics.

Comment: @WillieWong If it's only aesthetic, what would you do ? Is there a more practical way to do ?

Comment: I harbor the unrealistic aspiration that someday, someone other than myself will use one of the packages that I've written. So I always prefer to only include packages that I need in package definitions. // On the other hand, I maintain for my own personal use a few custom **class files** for various purposes. Most of the documents that I write using them don't call on all possible features, but I find it more convenient to just have everything in there rather than splitting features into options or packages.

Comment: At the heart of it, one interpretation of your question is whether you prefer the [KOMA-Script model](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) or the [Memoir model](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/memoir), which has its roots in the age-old question of whether one should adopt a modular or monolithic framework for software design. Depending on your intentions with this thing that you wrote, I can easily imagine arguing both ways.

Answer (score 1):

If your package requires others, then they should be included using `\RequirePackage`. If your package optionally depends on other packages, then they should be included only when the option is present. No other packages should be included.

In your example, `poster` should only include `minimalSet` if it depends on it.

Comment: Why "No other packages should be included" ?

Comment: Other packages shouldn't be included because they have no relation to the package you're writing. It's not uncommon for LaTeX packages to conflict with other packages. By included unnecessary packages, you're increasing the risk of a conflict in future uses of `poster` (for example) where `minimalSet` isn't necessary.